# How to calculate mass using integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

Determine the mass of the curved bar given the density $d = x$:

$$x(t) = \frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}, y(t) = \frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}, z(t) = t,t\in[0,1]$$

I calculated the integrals for these functions above. How do I proceed further? I'm having an exam tomorrow, please provide me some insight.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the mass, you need to compute the arc length, which is given by

$$\int_0^1 dt \;\rho(t) \sqrt{\left ( \frac{dx}{dt}\right )^2+\left ( \frac{dy}{dt}\right )^2+\left ( \frac{dz}{dt}\right )^2 }$$

where $\rho(t) = x(t)$ is the density.  Note that $x(t) = \cosh{t}$, $y(t)=\sinh{t}$.  Use the identities $\cosh^2{y}+\sinh^2{y}=\cosh{2 y}$ and $2 \cosh^2{z} = 1+\cosh{2 z}$.

I get for the mass

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}} + \frac1{4 \sqrt{2}} \left ( e^2 - \frac1{e^2}\right )$$

Comment: I understand the arc length part. What's the next step? What do I do when I calculate the integral?

Comment: @Tamás: what are the elements of the arc length integrand?  Looks to me like derivatives.

Comment: Oh, looks like I left out the density in the integral.  It looks like it is $x(t)$.  I will correct.

Comment: I know that density = mass/volume. I can calculate the volume using triple integrals. What about density? Can this approach work?

Comment: @Tamás: it is assumed here, it appears, that density in this case is mass per unit length.